# How to get recently added sort by option?

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I need to have recently added sort by option how can I get this.I searched google and also SE's but cannot found the solutions but not worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get recently added sort by option open `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/toolbar.php` and find and replace the below code will be in `line 232`

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
```

by

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
          if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='recentlyadded'){
              $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
          }
          else {
           $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
          }
        }
        return $this;
```

also in `line no 391` find and replace this code

```
public function setDefaultOrder($field)
{
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
        $this->_orderField = $field;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

with this code

```
 public function setDefaultOrder($field) {
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
        $this->_availableOrder = array(

            'recentlyadded'    => $this->__('Recently Added'),
            'name'        => $this->__('Name'),
            'price'       => $this->__('Price'),
        );
        $this->_orderField = $field;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

this should help you in getting the required recently added functionality if any queries please let me know.

Comment: what for the code to be pasted in line no 391??

Comment: It helps you maintain the dropdown option in frontend.

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'parent_item_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @dh47, how can we show this option only for specific categories?

Comment: @dh47, this will not load if any color and size filters are present,