# sort products by newest, discount, most sold, reviews" in products list page

Tags: product-list, magento-1, discount, sorting, review

On the products list page, we can see sort by "Position, name, price" as in default Magento.

How to sort by

1. newest products (uploaded recently)
2. Discount (highest discount products first)
3. Best seller (most sold products first)
4. Reviews (high rated products display first)

Please let me know if you need any clarification...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for -> [Recently Viewed see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48469/how-to-get-recently-added-sort-by-option/48471#48471)

for ->Sorting by rating

Copy the file

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` to

`app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`

in `list.php` find for this line

```
$this->_productCollection =$layer->getProductCollection();
```

which will be in around `line no 86` add the following code after that

```
$this->_productCollection->joinField('rating_summary', 'review_entity_summary', 'rating_summary', 'entity_pk_value=entity_id', array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'left')
```

now copy

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php` to

`app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php`

in config.php find for this code

```
$options = array(
    'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')
);
```

replace with

```
$options = array(
    'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
    'rating_summary' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Rating')
);
```

-->>for `BESTSELLER`

follow this procedure create a folder naming `Inchoo` and inside that folder place `Catalog` and inside catalog create 3 folders `Block`,`etc` and `Model` In `Block` add `Product` in `Product` add `List` and in `List` create a file and name it as `Toolbar.php` and ad this code into it

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        parent::setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'qty_ordered') {
                $this->getCollection()->getSelect()
                     ->joinLeft(
                            array('sfoi' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                             'e.entity_id = sfoi.product_id',
                             array('qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)')
                         )
                     ->group('e.entity_id')
                     ->order('qty_ordered ' . $this->getCurrentDirection());
            } else {
                $this->getCollection()
                     ->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())->getSelect();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

now in `etc` folder create a file with name `config.xml` and add this code

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inchoo_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Inchoo_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Inchoo_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_collection>Inchoo_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now in `Model` create a file naming `Config.php` and add this code.

```
<?php class Inchoo_Catalog_Model_Config extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Config
{
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray(),
            array('qty_ordered' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sold quantity'))
        );
    }
}
```

also create `Resource` folder in `Model` and in `Resource` folder create `Product` folder and create a file naming `Collection.php` and add following code.

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{
    protected function _getSelectCountSql($select = null, $resetLeftJoins = true)
    {
       $this->_renderFilters();
       $countSelect = (is_null($select)) ?
           $this->_getClearSelect() :
           $this->_buildClearSelect($select);

       if(count($countSelect->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
           $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
       }

       $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
       if ($resetLeftJoins) {
           $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();
       }
       return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

Now finally activate this module by going to `app/etc/modules` create a file `Inchoo_Catalog.xml` add this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Connect
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends />
        </Inchoo_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and for `SALE` I suggest you this [extension](https://amasty.com/improved-sorting.html) as I cannot find any programmatic way to achieve this.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will check and tell you soon....

Comment: is there anything else i have to do to get "rating" option in "sort by" in products list page.

i did cache and index management

but rating option is not displaying under :sort by" in products list page.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5403TsLa  = > list.php

http://pastebin.com/Z7WK7C1m  = > config.php

please check above files....

Comment: hmm the code works fine for me I cannot understand what is fault with your's

Comment: i will check it once again....

Comment: Or else just try that extension you can get everything in that

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot, 

it's working, but low rated products are displaying first, instead of high rated products.

what's the reason..?...

Comment: yea the code is in that way try changing `left` to `right`

Comment: i changed it.... it's not working for me....

Comment: Hi I have use same code you have suggested but i have problem in rewrite block. block code does not get executed