# Magento : How can I sort it by newest products instead of price or name for product list page?

Tags: sorting, sort

Is there any way to sort the products listing by newest?

[image]

Comment: Please refer this link : [How to add custom sort by](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49680/sort-products-by-newest-discount-most-sold-reviews-in-products-list-page) Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer  [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/14/magento-category-page-product-sorting/) to add the the sortable attribute for products.

Following this you will able to sort the products based on their created date, the attribute will be added in all the category pages, and from the admin panel you can show it for particular category also.