# How to filter product listing page based on discounts?

Tags: magento-1.7

By default on `listing page`,

I want to show `products` whose offer is `15%`.

```
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array('attribute'=>'offer','eq'=>'15'));
```

app\design\frontend\default\test\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

$_productCollection     = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('offers', '15')->Clear()->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

This I have done hardcode.

Comment: do you want to show all products with `15 % off` in one listing page ?

Comment: @Baby - app\design\frontend\default\test\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Comment: no, thats fine, do you want to show all products with 15 % off in one listing page ?

Comment: @Baby -  Yes I want to show all products with 15%. There will be dropdown on menu bar. On onchange condition will be change.

Comment: one option is you can create one category & associate all product with 15 % to that category, but this will not work with `dropdown`, but work only with `category-url` , check this once : [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49680/sort-products-by-newest-discount-most-sold-reviews-in-products-list-page)

Comment: @BabyinMagento Thank you so much. It helped me a lot. :) I have referred your this one link - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48469/how-to-get-recently-added-sort-by-option/48471#48471